# fill textbox based on combobox selection vb.net *data not bound

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Hi I have some code (below) that populates a combobox based on a MS Access Table. This should be simple but I cannot figure out the answer... does anyone know to display a textbox value based on the combobox selection?
ie: if name Joe is selected from combobox, the textbox can display ID: Joe123
Joe populates from the MS Access Table and the only two columns are Name and ID, please advise

```
    cn.Open()
    da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from tblCustExper_Reps", cn)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim r As DataRow
    For Each r In dt.Rows
        cmbISPRep.Items.Add(r("Name")).ToString()


    Next

    cn.Close()
```

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE - MY COMBOBOX IS NOT DATABOUND @plutonix

Comment: ...and if you put the names in it as Items, how do you expect to get something else from it?

Comment: not sure since im new.... advise would be helpful rather than just marking as duplicate instead of helping but it's okay I have since figured it out....